# Where to fetch user entity when users are stored in Active Directory?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor, automapper

Sometimes we have entities in the domain layer that are linked to users.

For instance:

```
class SomeEntity
{
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

A user might look like the following:

```
class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Now we want to store entities of type `SomeEntity` in our own database, but users should be stored in Active Directory.

To support this, we modify our `SomeEntity` class to look like this:

```
class SomeEntity
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

When we fetch entities of type `SomeEntity`, we can complement this with users from active directory to get the full domain model.

For instance:

```
SomeEntity entity = await _dbContext.SomeEntities.FindAsync(id);
User user = await _identityService.GetUserById(entity.UserId);
entity.User = user;
```

This should work, but when we have many different queries that fetch (subsets of) `SomeEntity`, we are going to rewrite the same fetching logic over and over again. When `SomeEntity` is an object that is nested within other objects, the fetching logic becomes even worse.

Is there any way we can make sure that when `SomeEntity` is fetched, we always also fetch `User`?

---

Some other things I've tried or seen online, that didn't fully solve the problem:

- Give `User` a getter that fetches that user once the property is used (This adds fetching logic to our domain model, which violates clean architecture principles). [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420581/how-to-store-active-directory-user-guid-using-entity-framework).
- Only including the `UserId` in the domain model and fetching the User once it's needed. (we'll have to rewrite logic, becomes especially difficult once objects are nested.)
- Doing the fetching with Entity Framework or Automapper. Seems dirty. Might work. Also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72001885/relationships-in-entity-framework-with-users-from-azuread) but didn't receive answers.

Technologies used:

- ASP.NET Core
- Blazor
- Entity Framework
- Automapper

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `SomeEntity` is a ef core model. While `User` is not. And it seems you have no plans to store the information of `User` in the Database maybe except the Identifier. So I would take your second option:

> Only including the UserId in the domain model and fetching the User
> once it's needed. (we'll have to rewrite logic, becomes especially
> difficult once objects are nested.)

Don't try to force the models into the design if it simply doesn't make sence.
The design should be based on the requirements and not vice versa.

The alternative option would be to store the User data in the DB and treat it like a database entity. But you would have to handle a sync/refresh between what is in your DB and what is in the AD if someone marry's or leaves for example.